# PHP session id is not constant on localhost (xampp, ubuntu)

Tags: php, html, session

I had a problem that I was struggling with a couple days ago, and the problem lies in my session id handling while using localhost (xampp local server).

What I now tried to do, is to create two separate pages, the first one randomizes a session id in such a way:

```
<?php

session_start();
$random_number = rand();
$_SESSION['random_number'] = $random_number;

?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en"
lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;
charset=utf-8"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<title>Understanding PHP sessions...Page 1</title>
</head>

<body>

<div id="contentarea">
    <div id="innercontentarea">
        <h2>Understanding PHP sessions...Page 1</h2>
        <p>Random number generated
            <span style="font-weight:bold;">
            <?php echo $_SESSION['random_number']; ?>
            </span>
        </p>

        <p>PHP session id
            <span style="text-decoration:underline;">
                <?php echo session_id(); ?>
            </span>
        </p>

        <a href="basic_session2.php">Go to next page</a>
    </div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

So, this creates a random session number here, and should output the same number on the second page basic_session2, which basically the same, but the difference is in session initialization, which is only:

```
    <?php 
       session_start();
    ?>

  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en"
lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;
charset=utf-8"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<title>Understanding PHP sessions...Page 2</title>
</head>

<body>

<div id="contentarea">
    <div id="innercontentarea">
        <h2>Understanding PHP sessions...Page 2</h2>
        <p>My Favorite movie is
        <span style="font-weight:bold;">
            <?php echo $_SESSION['random_number']; ?>
        </span>
        </p>

        <p>PHP session id
            <span style="text-decoration:underline;">
                <?php echo session_id(); ?>
            </span>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

But it echoes out a different random number! So, now, I am guessing there is a problem with my session cookie path, as this session number is not holding up.

The system I use is Ubuntu, and the localhost directory for xampp is a standard one. Do you know how to solve that issue, or maybe encountered such a problem?

Comment: Sorry, it is session_start() in my file, i just made a mistake while writing that manually here, as I didnt copy and paste this one.

Comment: can you add all relevant code from the second page, where you echo the session ID and the variable?

Comment: I can confirm this code is working for me. I don't see any code errors inside here.